# Check if at least one form field has been filled

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

To check if at least one forem field has been filled out, among other solutions, I am considering the following solution:

```
 var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myform')[0];

 form.getForm().getFields().each(function(field) {
       var value = field.getRawValue();
       if(value !== ''){
            //submit form
        }else{
             //error message
        }
  });
```

Since I have several forms that require filling in at least one field, I wanted to create a method in a Util file class and call this method in the controller; something like:

```
//Class Util
testFields: function(form){
    form.getForm().getFields().each(function(field) {
        var value = field.getRawValue();
        if(value !== ''){
           ...
        }
    });
},

//controller 
if(MyApp.util.Util.testFields(form) !== ''){ //does not work
     //submit form
}else{
    //error message
}
```

Is a solution like this feasible, or is it preferable to get the value of each field in the controller without iterating and testing if they are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that your util method should return a boolean like

```
//Class Util
testFields: function(form){
    var result = false;
    form.getForm().getFields().each(function(field) {
        if(field.getRawValue()){  // at least one field needs to be filled out
           result = true;
        }
    });
    return result;
},
```

Than your controller method should just test form like

```
//controller 
if(MyApp.util.Util.testFields(form)){
     form.submit();
}else{
    //error message
}
```